# Unexpected error message returned to user

Tags: python, python-3.x

The main menu options on the following code run fine, until an 'invalid entry' is made in either choice 1 or 2, even if the entry is correct. What happens next, is when choosing option 3 or 4 to display either file, then the 'invalid entry' error message from the name registration process, is displayed to the user, even though the user isn't in that menu option.

It seems like the script is looping somewhere but I can't figure out where. As I said, it only happens if that initial 'invalid entry' message is invoked in either option 1 or 2. If it isn't invoked, I can keep registering names and displaying files without problems.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
import sys


def main():

    main_menu_choice = input("""Please choose from the following
    1. Register a child.
    2. Register a staff member.
    3. Children.
    4. Staff.
    5. Exit.""")

    if main_menu_choice == "1":
        child_first_name = input("Enter the child's first name")
           # check that no empty string or digit is entered
        while child_first_name == "" or any(str.isdigit(c) for c in child_first_name):
            print("Invalid entry.")
            main()

        else:
            child_last_name = input("Enter the child's last name")

        while child_last_name == "" or any(str.isdigit(c) for c in child_last_name):
            print("Invalid entry.")
            main()

        child_name = (child_first_name + " " + child_last_name).title()

        file = open("Children.txt", 'a')
        file.write(child_name + "\n")
        file.close()
        main()

    elif main_menu_choice == "2":
        staff_first_name = input("Enter the staff member's first name")

        while staff_first_name == "" or any(str.isdigit(c) for c in staff_first_name):
            print("Sorry I didn't catch that\nPlease start again.")
            main()

        else:
            staff_last_name = input("Enter the staff member's last name")

        while staff_last_name == "" or any(str.isdigit(c) for c in staff_last_name):
            print("Sorry I didn't catch that\nPlease start again.")
            main()

        staff_name = (staff_first_name + " " + staff_last_name).title()

        file = open("Staff.txt", 'a')
        file.write(staff_name + "\n")
        file.close()
        main()

    elif main_menu_choice == "3":
        file = open("Children.txt", 'r')
        lineList = file.readlines()
        lineList.sort()  
        print("List of children's names in alphabetical order:")
        for line in lineList:
            print(line, end="")  
        file.close()

    elif main_menu_choice == "4":
        file = open("Staff.txt", 'r')
        lineList = file.readlines()
        lineList.sort()
        print("List of staff member's names in alphabetical order:")
        for line in lineList:
            print(line, end="")
        file.close()

    elif main_menu_choice == "5": 
        print("Exit.")
        sys.exit(0)

    else: #If an invalid choice was made from main_menu_choice
        print("Invalid Command, try again.")
        main()
main()
```

Comment: the first line should read: The main menu options on the following code run fine, until an 'invalid entry' is made in either choice 1 or 2, even after the entry is corrected.

Comment: If you print "Invalid entry." and call `main`, the rest of your function will still be run after your recursive call to `main()` completes. Your use of recursion in this function really makes it unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: doesn't the call to main() end the function then and there?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: Advice: Don't call `main()` inside `main`. If you want `main` to repeat, call it in a loop. This is not a good situation for recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem lies in:

```
while child_first_name == "" or any(str.isdigit(c) for c in child_first_name):
print("Invalid entry.") 
main()
```

You are using `while` in this condition check. This makes it keep on looping because the condition remains true.
Replace this condition check using an `if`.
Hope this helps.

EDIT:
To terminate the program at some point, you need to use `return`. You can add this after calling `main()` to avoid the rest of the code from being executed.
Try to avoid recursive calls when it's not necessary. This piece of code can be done using loops.

When you call the main() method from the main () method, the control doesn't simply jump to the top of the function and starts executing it again. Instead a whole new "copy" of the function is made in memory which is completely different from the one you just called from. That's a key to the concept of recursion.

Having said this, the control needs to "remember" where to return to after the new main() call has ended. Thus the return address is pushed into a stack. Now, no matter when the control returns to the calling main() again, it will execute the remaining lines of code (unless of course if the program is forcibly terminated from outside).

Comment: So this is where I get confused. I thought the call to main() would automatically cancel any further execution of the code to return it to the start of the main method. What exactly is happening if that's not the case? The code displays the menu options that are at the start of the main method immediately after a call to main() and that's what I want to happen, but obviously something else is happening and I'm missing it.  Using return still takes me back to the start but something else happens because I no longer get the errors.

Comment: @sleepylog Calling `main()` doesn't cancel anything. And it isn't a goto. It makes another call to `main` from _inside_ `main`. That means that two calls to `main` are in progress, the outer one and the inner one. The outer one continues once the inner one completes.